# OpenApiGenerate is generating model names that i dont specify

Tags: spring-boot, openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I am using openApiGenerate to generate the controller interfaces and model classes. But unfortunately it generates few models that dosent comply with what i provided. It is appending **Inner** word with some of the request models.

Is there anyway i can specify the name of models that it generates?

I am using the following in gradle -

```
openApiGenerate {
inputSpec = "$projectDir/openapi.yaml"
generatorName = 'spring'
outputDir = "$buildDir/generated"
apiPackage = 'fi.x.x'
modelPackage = 'fi.x.x.model'
library = 'spring-boot'
configOptions.set([
    interfaceOnly: "true"
])
```

}

Like for example we have operationId to specify the method name of the controller interfaces. I am looking for similar configurations to customize the model names generated and force not to pick other name than specified.

A modified snapshot of the Api :

```
paths:
/xyz/v1/con:
post:
  operationId: postCon
  tags:
    - Create Con
  summary: Create Con
  parameters:
      schema:
        type: string
      required: true
  requestBody:
    description: Con body payload
    required: true
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/CreateCon'
  responses:
    '200':
      description: Con created successfully
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/CreateConResponse'
```

So when i use the openApi generator with spring or java as generators, i get the model created with names like like - CreateConInner etc. Some of the name are however same as specified in schemas block.
Also that, i got an interface Api generated and the name is XyzApi (The first word in the api uri.) Is there a way to override this name as well.

As I said, previously, there is operationsId that does a similar task to rename the method name and that works.

Thanks!!
Nilotpal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide your openapi file.

But I assume you specified some models "inline". Thus they don't have a specific name so the generator has to give it one. Use **$ref** to make sure you declare every **object** type in your file. Then the generator won't try to guess a name for you it will use the name of the **schemas**.

It is not possible to configure the plug in in any way to achieve this. The openapi file has to be modified.

Comment: No! I have use d$ref and no inline models are provided. I just provided a snapshot of the api yaml and have modified my orignal post. Thanks!!

Comment: What about the refs inside _CreateCon_ or _CreateCronResponse_ ?

Comment: Do you have a minimal file ? Because I don't reproduce your problem

Comment: The problem is fixed and the error is what you said. We need to declare every object be it array or object under schemas and use $ref.